# Unable to insert large number of records results in timeouts, hung process

Tags: cassandra

We are inserting large records of data into open-source Cassandra database one by one using asp.net core and it result into timeout and process hanged, so I want to know about bulk data insert process if it is supported in Cassandra.
Kindly share some workable solution

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for us to provide you with a meaningful response without knowing details of what you have implemented. For example, if you are using CQL batches to bulk load the records then it could be the reason for the symptoms you mentioned.

The only recommendation I could give based on the limited info you supplied is that you should use the asynchronous API to maximise the throughput of your cluster.

Assuming you're using the C# driver, you should execute each insert statement asynchronously with:

```
var rs = await session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
```

For details, see the [Cassandra C# driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.19/) docs.

As a friendly suggestion, you should at least include a minimal sample code to show how you're inserting data. I've published [an article on the official Apache Cassandra website on asking good questions](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community/ask_good_questions.html) which you might find helpful. Cheers!